# Run Jenkins job with different environment variable

Tags: jenkins

I'm using jenkins 1.651. We have a Job which contains a shell. The shell contains:

```
echo ${VAR}
```

We are using the EnvInject plugin to define the content of our environment variable:

```
VAR=10
```

But sometimes we want to use another value for our env var:

```
VAR=20
```

Our env var must ben `10` in 50% of the cases, and `20` in the other 50%.
Is there a way or plugin which can help us to define easily how we want to run our job? With `VAR=10` or `VAR=20`?

We don't want to put `VAR=10` in comment, every time we want to run `VAR=20` and vice versa. So preferably a way which works withouth going inside our job configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Use Jenkins > Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build):

> The parameter are available as environment parameters. So e.g. a shell ($FOO, %FOO%) or Ant ( ${env.FOO} ) can access these values.

or the more sophisticated [Extensible Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin) and [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin).